# Timestamps on Messenger - iOS and OSX

Tags: ios, macos, messages, sms

I can very easily see timestamps for texts (SMS) and messages (wifi? not really sure what this is) on iOS messenger by swiping to the left. However, in the Messenger app on OSX (10.11.6 El Capitan), I cannot for the life of my get these timestamps to appear (swiping, right-clicking a message, app options and context menus, etc.)

**How do I show timestamps for messages in the Messages app on OSX?** The best that Messages gives me is a collection of messages that is "around" a timestamp that is apparently relevant, e.g.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hover your cursor over the relevant message for a few seconds, the time & date will pop up in a tooltip.

[image]

Picture with clear date also shown, to demonstrate it's accurate.
<sub>& those verification codes are well out of date.. ;-)</sub>

Comment: How unintuitive... I guess my own impatience gets the better of me! I tend not to hover on things for very long. Thanks!

Comment: I actually like how it doesn't litter a convo with cruft; you kind of know if a convo all took place within a few mins, or was stretched over several hours/days.

Comment: I wish it was the same way as in iOS. Like you swipe, on a trackpad or click and drag on a mouse.

Comment: 2018 version you can accidentally like or dislike something with no ability to change it. Majority of their best features are inconspicuously missing for anyone who has the messenger but no fb. Just randomly made an ass of myself looking for timestamps. My hatred for fb remains loyal XD Edit:
Here’s the description that helped me figure it out:
‘Tap the message and then immediately bring your finger back off’